# How to see fetched changesets using Git in Netbeans 7.4 that are not merged

Tags: git, netbeans

In Netbeans 7.4, you can fetch changesets from origin/master using Git. If origin/master has moved ahead of where your master is, how do you see those changesets?

If I use Team > Show Changes, the fetched changes don't show up. It is obvious because the "origin/master" label isn't there.

If I enter search options of:

From: master 
To/Branch: origin/master

Then I can see them both on one screen. I'm looking for a better way.

I don't see any improvement in Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: Are you actually fetching the changes?  In Git parlance, you'd want to pull them.

Comment: Yes, the changes are fetched. They are in the local repo. If I use gitk or Eclipse, the changesets are there and labeled with origin/master. The purpose is to watch what other people are doing, but not merge just yet.

Comment: So maybe I'm confused.  You say that you're *fetching*, but in Git, a fetch doesn't update your local reference to point to the same spot as the remote reference, so they wouldn't be in your local repo.

Comment: My understanding is that fetch pulls changesets from a remote repo, but doesn't merge them. pull = fetch + merge. See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: A fetch would download them to my local repo, just wouldn't update my working copy.

Comment: Yes.  That's as I understand it too.  This is why your verbiage confused me; you mentioned the changes being in the local repo.  That said, you're looking for a good way to see what changes are happening between your copy of `master` and `origin/master`?  Do you require the use of Netbeans for this?

Comment: When I mean the changes are in my local repo, I mean my .git folder. I don't absolutely require Netbeans, but most of the people in our development group at work use it. Some of us use Eclipse, and we have the command line git tools and gitk available to us. Just looking for a better way in the tools most people around here are familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
From: master 
To/Branch: origin/master
```

is the best way